# is google reCAPTCHA required for multi factor authentication

Tags: recaptcha, multi-factor-authentication

I understand the purpose for CAPTCHA and MFA. However, is 2nd factor authentication not human intervention proving he is not a bot. is that not enough ? what are the chances of successfully bruteforcing two credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

You may ask for the signature (Wacom or any other drawing tablets) followed by the fingerprint. But it will make the MFA complex to implement. Better to fall back to time tested methods of a lock and key.
Check [FIDO alliance](https://fidoalliance.org/) where authentication is done locally using a device. Big banks already are testing using it by providing customers a device.